# PDF file uploading. Appears blank

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When testing in postman my API which generates a PDF file will allow me toe download the generated file and view the PDF in full.

When adding this file to my S3 bucket the file appears blank.

Here are the params I'm using the set the file type etc

```
                 let params = {
                     Key: objKey,
                     ContentType: 'application/pdf',
                     Body: file,
                     CacheControl: "no-cache",
                   Metadata: {
                     Title: this.header,
                     Type: this.select,
                     Notes: this.description,
                     Date: moment().format("L h:mm:ss"),
                     User: this.userName
                     },
                          ACL: "public-read"
                     };
```

Just wondering if I have missed something in here.

Comment: Please show more of your code. Also, when you look at the file in S3 what is the file size in bytes?

Comment: File size is 1.2mb